# What's better for large datasets in reinforcement learning? Dictionary, numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, dictionary, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement a Chess AI with Reinforcement Learning, i'm using the Q-learn algorithm and, to keep track of the q-values that each state have, as a starting point, i implemented a dictionary of dictionaries. (in other words, to keep track of large amount of values that holds a large amount of values, i implemented a dictionary of dictionary)

This implementation worked smooth in small and dumb scenarios.
For example, having the following board, if the whites are the only ones that can move, it gets a checkmate in less than 3 minutes.
[Initial testing board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh2WA.png)

I've tried to minimize the computational requeriments for each step in the q-learning algorithm, but nothing seems to work, so, as the mentioned algorithm works around the q-table itself, it's really probable that i'm not using the optimal structure.

Right now this is the method that gets/initialize the values for each state-action (the first dictionary is the state, the second the different actions (future states) that that state does).
`
def get_qdict(self, state, action):
string_state = self.stateToString(state)
string_action = self.stateToString(action)

```
if string_state in self.q_dict:
    if string_action in self.q_dict[string_state]:
        return self.q_dict[string_state][string_action]
    else:
        self.q_dict[string_state][string_action] = 0
        return 0
else:
    self.q_dict[string_state]={}
    self.q_dict[string_state][string_action] = 0
    return 0

self.q_dict[string_state][string_action] = 0
return 0
```

`
*The stateToString transform the type array position to a string*

The problem comes as i try to add the black movements in the equation or i set a more complex scenario, the time needed increases exponentially, needing hours to get somewhere.

For example, for each episode in the previous scenario (the one with just the black king, and white rook and king) it takes around **0,01s**.
While for each episode in the scenario where blacks can do a movement, the time needed for episode is around **0,3s**.

**How could i fix this? Should i implement the q-table as a numpy? Or is it better if i implement it as a pandas DataFrame**
Or, is it normal that when i set the second scenario, the times augments that much?

Comment: Without having understood every detail of your question (e.g., what is the scenario where blacks can do a move), I would say a pandas DataFrame is the most efficient and easy-to-handle way.

Comment: Q-learning is not feasible for chess. Chess has GIGANTIC state space, this will not in a memory in all machines in the world combined. You will need to represent Qs not as a lookupdict, but rather as a function, e.g. neural network (or at least a linear model)